# How do I make a find dialog in StyledTextCtrl?

Tags: python, wxpython

There is an existing question on this subject: [Find text dialog with wxpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827587/find-text-dialog-with-wxpython), but it's in TextCtrl. So I changed the TextCtrl to StyledTextCtrl, and tested it. But I got this error:

```
in wxStyledTextCtrl::SetStyle(): not implemented
```

How do I make the SetStyle a selection instead so that you can click away? Here is my code:

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.tc = stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_WORDWRAP)
        self.bt_find = wx.Button(self, -1, "find")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button, self.bt_find)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_FIND, self.on_find)

        self.pos = 0
        self.size = 0
        #
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.tc, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer.Add(self.bt_find, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

    def on_button(self, event):
        self.txt = self.tc.GetValue()
        self.data = wx.FindReplaceData()   # initializes and holds search parameters
        self.dlg = wx.FindReplaceDialog(self.tc, self.data, 'Find')
        self.dlg.Show()

    def on_find(self, event):
        fstring = self.data.GetFindString()          # also from event.GetFindString()
        self.pos = self.txt.find(fstring, self.pos)
        self.size = len(fstring)
        self.tc.SetStyle(self.pos, self.pos+self.size, wx.TextAttr("red", "black"))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-dev/lXjFD9b1Q2c

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I found a selection method(answer below), but it makes an error. I explained the error under my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StyledTextCtrl` looks like a highly complex beast and I can only assume that you will have to read the `scintilla` documents exhustively http://www.scintilla.org/
The link in my comment was pointing at using `SetStyling` function not `AddSelection`.
This is what I managed using that:

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.tc = stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_WORDWRAP)
        self.bt_find = wx.Button(self, -1, "find")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button, self.bt_find)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_FIND, self.on_find)

        self.pos = 0
        self.size = 0
        #
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.tc, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer.Add(self.bt_find, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

    def on_button(self, event):
        self.txt = self.tc.GetValue()
        self.data = wx.FindReplaceData()   # initializes and holds search parameters
        dlg = wx.FindReplaceDialog(self.tc, self.data, 'Find')
        dlg.Show()

    def on_find(self, event):
        self.tc.StartStyling(pos=0, mask=0xFF)
        self.tc.SetStyling(length=len(self.txt), style=0)
        fstring = event.GetFindString()
        self.size = len(fstring)
        while True:
            self.pos = self.txt.find(fstring, self.pos)
            if self.pos < 0:
                break
            self.tc.StyleSetSpec(1, "fore:#FF0000,back:#000000")
            self.tc.StartStyling(pos=self.pos, mask=0xFF)
            self.tc.SetStyling(length=self.size, style=1)
            self.pos += 1
        self.pos = 0

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App()
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for all your help, you're a legend

Comment: One more question, how do I make it so that when you click, it removes the Styling?

Comment: That would be a different question. However, the answer is above. The first two lines of the `on_find` clears the previous style, so prehaps bind self.tc to EVT_LEFT_DOWN and use those 2 lines

Comment: `self.tc.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.remove_find)` might improve your odds.