# How do I make my Find dialog not interfere with lexer in StyledTextCtrl?

Tags: wxpython

I need help in making my find dialog not interfere with my lexer. I used the find dialog in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880227/how-do-i-make-a-find-dialog-in-styledtextctrl) but it uses SetStyles which interferes with my lexer. Along with messing up the syntax highlighting, when I try to do the Find again, it just highlights random things. Any help is appreciated!

Editor:

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc
import keyword

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.tc = stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_WORDWRAP)
        self.bt_find = wx.Button(self, -1, "find")
        self.bt_css = wx.Button(self, -1, "CSS")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button, self.bt_find)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_FIND, self.on_find)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.CSS, self.bt_css)

        self.pos = 0
        self.size = 0
        #
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.tc, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer.Add(self.bt_find, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)
        sizer.Add(self.bt_css, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

    def on_button(self, event):
        self.txt = self.tc.GetValue()
        self.data = wx.FindReplaceData()   # initializes and holds search parameters
        dlg = wx.FindReplaceDialog(self.tc, self.data, 'Find')
        dlg.Show()

    def on_find(self, event):
        self.tc.StartStyling(pos=0, mask=0xFF)
        self.tc.SetStyling(length=len(self.txt), style=0)
        fstring = event.GetFindString()
        self.size = len(fstring)
        while True:
            self.pos = self.txt.find(fstring, self.pos)
            if self.pos < 0:
                break
            self.tc.StyleSetSpec(1, "fore:#FF0000,back:#000000")
            self.tc.StartStyling(pos=self.pos, mask=0xFF)
            self.tc.SetStyling(length=self.size, style=1)
            self.pos += 1
        self.pos = 0

    def CSS(self, e):
        self.tc.SetLexer(stc.STC_LEX_CSS)
        self.tc.SetKeyWords(0, " ".join(keyword.kwlist))
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_ATTRIBUTE, 'fore:#0000FF')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_CLASS, 'fore:#0000FF')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_COMMENT, 'fore:#008000')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_DEFAULT, 'fore:#000000')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_DIRECTIVE, 'fore:#0000FF')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_DOUBLESTRING, 'fore:#800080')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_ID, 'fore:#008080')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_IDENTIFIER, 'fore:#000000')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_IDENTIFIER2, 'fore:#000000')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_IMPORTANT, 'fore:#000000')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_OPERATOR, 'fore:#800000')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_PSEUDOCLASS, 'fore:#008080')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_SINGLESTRING, 'fore:#800080')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_TAG, 'fore:#008080')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_UNKNOWN_IDENTIFIER, 'fore:#000000')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_UNKNOWN_PSEUDOCLASS, 'fore:#008080')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_VALUE, 'fore:#668B8B')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App()
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: In `on_find` try setting the lexer to null `self.tc.SetLexer(stc.STC_LEX_NULL)`

Comment: @RolfofSaxony It didn't do anything :/

Comment: It works well on Linux, are you on a different OS

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Where did you put the self.tc.SetLexer(stc.STC_LEX_NULL) ?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I am using Windows btw

Comment: First line of the `on_find` function. Perhaps you should attach images of what you have and what you want. As it is, it's open to interpretation.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Code: https://pastebin.com/RZNPm1ur Video of what's happening: https://imgur.com/a/oeLImVQ

Answer (score 1):

At first, you should use style number that is not used by lexer, see style codes in `_stc.py`.
You can also use `Colourise(0, -1)` method to clear your custom styling and reapply default lexer's colorizing to whole document (see StyledTextCtrl [documentation](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl.html#wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl.Colourise)).

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc
import keyword

SCE_FIND = 24  # style for highlighting of matching text

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.tc = stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_WORDWRAP)
        self.bt_find = wx.Button(self, -1, "find")
        self.bt_css = wx.Button(self, -1, "CSS")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button, self.bt_find)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_FIND, self.on_find)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_FIND_CLOSE, self.on_find_close)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.CSS, self.bt_css)

        self.pos = 0
        self.size = 0
        #
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.tc, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer.Add(self.bt_find, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)
        sizer.Add(self.bt_css, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(SCE_FIND, "fore:#FF0000,back:#000000")

    def on_button(self, event):
        self.txt = self.tc.GetValue()
        self.data = wx.FindReplaceData()   # initializes and holds search parameters
        dlg = wx.FindReplaceDialog(self.tc, self.data, 'Find', wx.FR_NOUPDOWN | wx.FR_NOMATCHCASE)
        dlg.Show()

    def on_find(self, event):
        fstring = event.GetFindString()
        self.size = len(fstring)
        while True:
            self.pos = self.txt.find(fstring, self.pos)
            if self.pos < 0:
                break

            self.tc.StartStyling(pos=self.pos, mask=0xFF)
            self.tc.SetStyling(length=self.size, style=SCE_FIND)
            self.pos += 1
        self.pos = 0

    def on_find_close(self, event):
        self.tc.Colourise(0, -1)

    def CSS(self, e):
        self.tc.SetLexer(stc.STC_LEX_CSS)
        self.tc.SetKeyWords(0, " ".join(keyword.kwlist))
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_ATTRIBUTE, 'fore:#0000FF')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_CLASS, 'fore:#0000FF')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_COMMENT, 'fore:#008000')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_DEFAULT, 'fore:#000000')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_DIRECTIVE, 'fore:#0000FF')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_DOUBLESTRING, 'fore:#800080')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_ID, 'fore:#008080')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_IDENTIFIER, 'fore:#000000')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_IDENTIFIER2, 'fore:#000000')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_IMPORTANT, 'fore:#000000')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_OPERATOR, 'fore:#800000')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_PSEUDOCLASS, 'fore:#008080')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_SINGLESTRING, 'fore:#800080')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_TAG, 'fore:#008080')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_UNKNOWN_IDENTIFIER, 'fore:#000000')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_UNKNOWN_PSEUDOCLASS, 'fore:#008080')
        self.tc.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_CSS_VALUE, 'fore:#668B8B')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App()
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! However the Find dialog is not working for some reason, I am using Windows

Comment: It works without the syntax highlighting, but with it nothing happens

Comment: @oystrich I think this question explains what I want better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243269/how-do-i-make-find-dialog-use-selections-instead-of-setstyles Thank you so much

Comment: Please see screenshot, it should work with syntax highlighting too: [link](https://i.imgur.com/CihoEGZ.png)